Reduce spacing before/after `\Pr`
I have an overfull hbox, and the badness wears heavily on my soul.
It comes from an expression of the type
$$\dots = \Pr_{G\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)}[G\in A]$$

This leads to latex inserting a large space between both = and \Pr, and \Pr and the left square brace [. See the attached photo.

Is there a way to remove/minimize this inserted spacing? The hbox really isn't that overfull. I could fix it. I will fix it. But how?

Very similar math mode - How to extend the text under summation symbol without making extra space - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange --- although I don't know if the difference between ∑ and Pr is significant enough (e.g. you need additional mathop wrapping).

That works! I was remembering \smash, but wasn't able to get it to do what I wanted.

Unrelated: Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

the image you show is clearly not made by the code you posted.

Sometimes there just isn't much of an advantage in cramming too much information in a limited amount of space; see row 1 below, which employs a \smashoperator directive -- a macro provided by the mathtools package, a superset of the amsmath package -- to get rid of the whitespace on both sides of \Pr.
For the material at hand, I can think of four alternatives to placing the conditioning term, G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2), directly below \Pr.

I might side-set rather than under-set the conditioning term; see row 2.

I might place the conditioning clause after the main result; see row 3.

If it's necessary to mention that the probability is conditional on the properties of the distribution G, I might write \Pr\nolimits_G[g\in A] and still state the conditioning term after the main result; see row 4.

Last but not least, if you've already informed your readers that G is a normally distributed random vector with a certain mean (0) and covariance matrix (\sigma^2), you could just omit the term \text{ for $G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$} entirely; see row 5. Given that you've mentioned that you're trying to fix a mild "overfull hbox" warning message, this may be the way you want to proceed.



\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\smashoperator' macro; load 'amsmath' automatically
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\dots &= \smashoperator{\Pr_{G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)}} [g\in A] \\
\dots &= \Pr\nolimits^{}_{G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)} [g\in A] \\
\dots &= \Pr[g\in A] \text{ for $G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$} \\
\dots &= \Pr\nolimits_G[g\in A] \text{ for $G\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$} \\
\dots &= \Pr\nolimits_G[g\in A]
\end{align*}

\end{document}


If the word "for" isn't quite appropriate, feel free to replace it with a better-fitting word.
